# Computing integrals in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to actually compute $\int \sqrt{\cosh{y}-\cos{x}}e^{inx} dx$ 
in mathematica. As an example i tried computing $\int \sqrt{1-\cos{x}}e^{inx} dx$ 
and got a result. But when i try $\int \sqrt{2-\cos{x}}e^{inx} dx$ i do not get any result. Note that $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Any fixes please.

The code i used was:

Integrate $\bigg[\sqrt{2-Cos[x]} Exp[i*n*x],x\bigg]$

```
Integrate[Sqrt[2-Cos[x]]Exp[I n x],x]
```

Comment: What is the code you used to do those integrals?  (no screenshot please; just plaintext code)

Comment: Integrate [\sqrt{(2-Cos[x]} Exp[i*n*x], x]..i actually used square root symbol  that is ctrl+2 in mathematica

Comment: @user69312 Would you add the code (properly formatted) in your original post? You can edit your post using the "edit" link right under it on the left. Here are some guidelines for posting fancy-formatted code so that it remains readable in this site: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951

Comment: i have updated the post with the code..thanks

Comment: Try again;  I edited your post for guidance.

Comment: Built-ins in MMA are all capitalised, even the imaginary unit.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this integral can be computed analytically? If not, then use `NIntegrate`. What are the conditions on `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function cannot be integrated with unknown `n`, because its form changes with different values for n:

```
Table[Integrate[Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]] Exp[I n x], x], {n, 0, 3}]
```

1:

> 2 EllipticE[x/2, -2], 
>    1/3 (-4 EllipticE[x/2, -2] + 6 EllipticF[x/2, -2] - 
>       I Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]] (-5 + 2 Cos[x/2]^2 + Cos[x] + 2 I Sin[x]))

2:

> 2/15 (I + 
>      Cot[x]) (13 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-1 + Cos[x]] Sqrt[1 + Cos[x]]
>        EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]]], 1/3] (Cos[x] - I Sin[x]) - 
>      5 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-1 + Cos[x]] Sqrt[1 + Cos[x]]
>        EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]]], 1/3] (Cos[x] - I Sin[x]) + 
>      Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]] (8 - 8 Cos[2 x] + 4 I Sin[x] + 5 I Sin[2 x]))

3:

> 1/35 Csc[x] (Cos[(3 x)/2] + 
>      I Sin[(3 x)/2]) (132 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-1 + Cos[x]] Sqrt[1 + Cos[x]]
>        EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]]], 1/
>        3] (Cos[(3 x)/2] - I Sin[(3 x)/2]) - 
>      50 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[-1 + Cos[x]] Sqrt[1 + Cos[x]]
>        EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[2 - Cos[x]]], 1/
>        3] (Cos[(3 x)/2] - I Sin[(3 x)/2]) + 
>      Sqrt[2 - 
>        Cos[x]] (85 Cos[x/2] - 14 Cos[(3 x)/2] - 71 Cos[(5 x)/2] - 
>         39 I Sin[x/2] + 22 I Sin[(3 x)/2] + 61 I Sin[(5 x)/2]))

Comment: Nevertheless I suspect that one can derive a recurrence relation for these elliptic integrals... (assuming integer $n$)

Comment: @J.M. Sure, there are definitely patterns in the solutions, but then he should at least define $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and even then, is that something you could easily get from Mathematica in this case?

Comment: @J.M. `, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers` does nothing.

Comment: Not really; my experience with elliptic integrals in *Mathematica* is not very rosy. The expressions returned tend to be more complicated than they have to be, so I fall back on semi-manual derivation (using *Mathematica* only for tedious algebra), with the guidance of Byrd/Friedman.

Comment: Thank u all for your insights and yes n ∈ Z..I agree it gets tedious with elliptic functions.

Comment: @J.M. Could you please specify what would your approach be without Mathematica in order to see a recursive pattern please?

Comment: That's more a [math question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) than a *Mathematica* question, @user...

Comment: thanks.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837342/question-on-integral-computation